flutter app running issue related to dependancies
PS E:\flutter codes\apps\cropco> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1904 in debug mode...
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:9: Error: Expected ';' after this.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:19: Error: Expected ';' after this.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:27: Error: Operator declarations must be preceded by the keyword 'operator'.
Try adding the keyword 'operator'.
codec and their platform-specific
^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:27: Error: A method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list to the method declaration.
codec and their platform-specific
^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:28: Error: Expected '{' before this.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:28: Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:28: Error: Expected ';' after this.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:3: Error: 'codec' isn't a type.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:284:21: Context: This isn't a type.
final MethodCodec codec;
^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:13: Error: Type 'their' not found.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:3: Error: Not a constant expression.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:13: Error: 'their' isn't a type.
codec and their platform-specific
^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:487:12: Error: The method '_invokeMethod' isn't defined for the class 'MethodChannel'.

'MethodChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '_invokeMethod'.
return _invokeMethod(method, missingOk: false, arguments: arguments);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:581:18: Error: Superclass has no method named '_invokeMethod'.
return super._invokeMethod(method, missingOk: true, arguments: arguments);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:277:9: Error: Constructor is marked 'const' so all fields must be final.
const MethodChannel(this.name, [this.codec = const StandardMethodCodec(), BinaryMessenger? binaryMessenger ])
^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:9: Context: Field isn't final, but constructor is 'const'.
codec and their platform-specific
^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:19: Context: Field isn't final, but constructor is 'const'.
codec and their platform-specific
^
/E:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:28: Context: Field isn't final, but constructor is 'const'.
codec and their platform-specific
^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'E:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

I am getting this error while trying to run all the flutter apps which was running properly till morning*

I have tried changing dependancy ,clean the project,rebuilt it,also restarted the PC ,created new project and copy the codes of previous project but these didn't worked out...........
my pubspec.yaml:
name: your_project_name
description: A new Flutter project

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

my main.dart file:
import 'package:cropco/screens/frontscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

final theme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 131, 57, 0),
  ),
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(),
);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FrontScreen(),
    );
  }
}


Hello and welcome! I believe you could get more help if you paste your pubspec.yaml and perhaps your main.dart files.

I have added the pubspec.yaml and my main.dart . Now if you could help me out....

Well done. It's weird, because it looks like your platform_channel.dart contains syntax errors. This is not supposed to happen because it's part of the Flutter core libraries. Did you modify this file somehow? I would just remove E:/src/flutter and reinstall it.

Thanks  a lot .... reinstalling E:/scr/flutter  worked and now the apps are running as before.

Great! Still, I have no clue why this could have happened. :-D
